# Passing dropdown list value to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

hi i have been able to upload image path to database with codeigniter, but i cant seem to pass the option of category to database. i have dropdown menu with 2 option and then i want to pass it to controller so i can insert it to the database.

here is my code:

my view

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
<br />
<select name="album" id="album"> // my dropdown list
    <option value="staff">Album Staff</option>
    <option value="gallery">Gallery</option>
</select>
<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my controller

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            $upload_info=$this->upload->data();
            $insert_data = array(
            'imgfilename' => $upload_info['file_name'],
            'imgfilepath' => $upload_info['file_path'],
            'album' => $this->input->post('album') //trying to get the value from select in view
            );
            $this->db->insert('db_images', $insert_data);

        }
    }
}
?>
```

how should it be done? any solution?

Comment: do a var_dump($this->input->post()) and paste here the results

Comment: print_r($insert_data );  and  check the array elements

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried using `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["album"])` to see how that works? Setting global_xss_filter to true could protect/affect a few things. Strangely, you can't always tell what is interfering with your code. That's why you should have more than one options. Try the line above and see if you get results. If you do, you could do this:

```
$album = "";
$albums = array("gallery", "staff"); //restrict types of allowed albums
$str = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["album"]); //clean up the string

if(in_array($str, $albums)){
$album = $str; //get the album to send to database
}
```